How to get LTP & OHLC values from Alice Blue broker using python
I just started python learning, Im trying to automate my trading using python with AliceBlue broker.
For my script im giving my User ID, API Key as input, using this data I derived NFO, BFO master list, API ENcription Key, Session ID (also 2times SHA256 of session ID for ws connection), Position Book, Holdings, limits, A/c Details, Basket Order and other order types.
But without Live data, I could not automate the orders. As I checked in internet, for live data we need to use Websocket in python.
Someone help me how to get the live data using websocket in python.
Thanks in advance
